# Why crontab can't use ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, cron

For some kind of reason, I can't use `ruby` in `crontab`.

In the console, if I run `echo $(ruby -v)`, it will return the version of `ruby` perfectly.

However, I put the following code in crontab

```
* * * * * echo $(ruby -v) >> 123.rb
* * * * * echo "123" >> 123.rb
```

Then I notice that, the `123.rb` only contains a lot of `123`.

So I checked the path of `ruby`.

```
root@myserver:~# which ruby
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby
```

Basically, I am the only one user who can access this server, so I install all application as `root`.
Should I and how do I add some `link` to enable the permission for `root`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In crontab, type full pathes:

```
* * * * * echo $(/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby -v) >> 123.rb
* * * * * echo "123" >> 123.rb
```

should work.

Or, add `$PATH` variable:

In console:

`echo $PATH`

Copy value, in crontab file add:

```
export $PATH="<copied pathes>:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/"

* * * * * echo $(ruby -v) >> 123.rb
* * * * * echo "123" >> 123.rb
```